# Blank space before http in anchor tag

Tags: html, url, anchor

The space was present (Highlighted as ) after the opening of href=" is it impact anything in our HTML code?

SYNTAX:

```
<a href="<Space>http......" </a>
```

In Coding:

```
<a href=" http......" </a>
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Matheen

Comment: the space wont effect anything what u really want?

Answer (score 2):

According to the W3C, the `href` attribute is:

> The href attribute on `a` ... elements must have a value that is a valid **[URL potentially surrounded by spaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/urls.html#valid-url-potentially-surrounded-by-spaces)**.
>
> The href attribute on a and area elements is not required; when those elements do not have href attributes they do not create hyperlinks.

<sub>http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href, **emphasis** mine.</sub>

The definition of an "*URL potentially surrounded by spaces*" is:

> A string is a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces if, after stripping leading and trailing whitespace from it, it is a valid non-empty URL.

<sub>http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/urls.html#valid-url-potentially-surrounded-by-spaces</sub>

So, yes: you can legitimately surround your `href`'s URL with spaces if you wish, so long as it evaluates to a legitimate URL once those leading and trailing spaces are removed.

Comment: You should cite the approved HTML5 Recommendation, not a draft that is over 2 years old (even if there is no change in the texts quoted).

Comment: @Jukka: honestly, I hadn't realised that this was the old version... :/

Answer (score 1):

If you are just asking whether whitespace inside an "href" tag will be problematic then,
no, those two formats should be identical in terms of performance. Although I don't see any good reason to have a space there, even for readability.
Here is a Jfiddle to illustrate.

```
 <a href=" https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
 <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j5hm98g5/

Please ask your question more clearly if this doesn't help.